# How to implement onload attribute in frameset

Tags: javascript, onload, frameset

How can I implement the onload attribute in a page containing a frameset? The problem is- frameset does not allow the `<body></body>` tag.

And

```
<div onload="function_name();"><frameset>....</frasmeset></div>
```

is not working.

Comment: You could bind to the `onload` event of the root `<html>` element in your frameset, but why are you using `<frameset>` in the first place?

Comment: you can use frames collection and then try something like this frames[0].onload = function() {};

Comment: Did you mean, embed the `onload` into the `<html>` tag? It is not working. I am developing an online exam system, where the exam page is divided into frames; one frame will display questions, one will display list of unanswered questions, etc, hence I am using <`frameset>`.

Comment: @Givi: Can you explain a bit more about how to use frames collection in this case?

Comment: You can read about frames http://javascript.info/tutorial/frames-and-iframes . and use iframe instead of frameset if you want to use it inline